# How to render postgresql table data to HTML with smarter code?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, fetch

I'm studying a bootcamp, and running a project that builds up a car rental website.

I need to employ the skill of postgresql (with knex), javascript, node.js, and bootstrap.

To display information in UI for users to confirm car booking, I prepare the following code:

```
async function getBookings() {
const res = await fetch('/reg/user');
const resJson = await res.json();


let html = "";
for (let booking of resJson) {
  console.log(booking);

  html += `<tr>
  <td>${booking.id}</td>
  <td>${booking.username}</td>
  <td>${booking.email}</td>
  <td>${booking.phone}</td>
  </tr>`;
  }

  document.querySelector("#booking-table").innerHTML = html;

}

getBookings();
```

The code works, but it seems there are two drawbacks:

1. it is rather old-school - using td tr rather than div;
2. it limits the potential of adjusting the table scale - only the four named items (id, username, email, phone) can be displayed. If more or less items are needed in the future, I need to hard-code the item name again.

Is there any smarter way to render database information to HTML?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using a template engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) along with `map` to simplfy the code somewhat.

In order to show the snippet working I removed fetch.

```js
const sampleBookings = [{
  id: 1,
  username: "bob",
  email: "bob@email.com",
  phone: "1234567"
},{
  id: 1,
  username: "jane",
  email: "jane@email.com",
  phone: "7654321"
}
];

const dummyLoader = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve(sampleBookings);
  });
};


async function getBookings() {
  // Obviously fetch in live version.
  dummyLoader().then(bookings => {
    document.querySelector("#booking-table")
            .innerHTML = bookings.map(({ id, username, email, phone}) => `
                <tr>
                <td>${id}</td>
                <td>${username}</td>
                <td>${email}</td>
                <td>${phone}</td>
                </tr>
            `)
            .join('');
  });
}

getBookings();
```

```html
<table id="booking-table">

</table>
```

Here is the code using `fetch`, but obviously it will not run.

```js
const getBookings() => {
  fetch('/res/bookings').then(res => res.json())
                        .then(bookings => {
                          document.querySelector("#booking-table")
                            .innerHTML = bookings.map(({ id, username, email, phone}) => `
                                <tr>
                                <td>${id}</td>
                                <td>${username}</td>
                                <td>${email}</td>
                                <td>${phone}</td>
                                </tr>
                            `)
                            .join('');
  });
}

getBookings();
```